# Getting junk value(com.intuit.karate.ScriptObjectMap@XXXX ) when i call karate feature( using Karate.call) in javascript

Tags: karate

I am trying to call a karate feature in javascript and capture its response as below, but while doing, the response from karate.call is showing junk value(com.intuit.karate.ScriptObjectMap@XXXX ) . kindly help to get the actual values from karate.call or suggest me any best idea ?

```
function RequestMandator(featurepath,data) {
var Mandator = [];
data.forEach(function(data){    
var TransferId =  data.TransferID;
var FocusKey = data.TransferID + ':';
var TimeStamp = data.LastUpdate;
var result = karate.call(featurepath, { input: [TransferId, FocusKey,TimeStamp ] });
karate.log('Added Mandator :', result);
Mandator.push(result);        
})
return Mandator;
}
```

Output:

```
11:32:53.307 [main] WARN  com.intuit.karate - xml parsing failed, response data type set to string: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 5; columnNumber: 15; Open quote is expected for attribute "border" associated with an  element type  "table".
11:32:53.310 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate - Added Mandator : com.intuit.karate.ScriptObjectMap@102d92c4 

Error:
    com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateFileNotFoundException: C:\XXXXXXXX\com.intuit.karate.ScriptObjectMap@7808fb9,com.intuit.karate.ScriptObjectMap@25d958c6,com.intuit.karate.ScriptObjectMap@5eeedb60,com.intuit.karate.ScriptObjectMap@6ad6fa53,com.intuit.karate.ScriptObjectMap@6f099cef,com.intuit.karate.ScriptObjectMap@2d66530f,com.intuit.karate.ScriptObjectMap@25b865b5 (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
    at com.intuit.karate.FileUtils.getFileStream(FileUtils.java:146)
    at com.intuit.karate.FileUtils.readFile(FileUtils.java:110)
    at com.intuit.karate.ScriptBridge.read(ScriptBridge.java:67)
```

Comment: The error details look like you're passing invalid XML ("open quote is expected for attribute border).

Comment: Hi Robert, if i do it with out karate.call in javascript ... i am not getting any error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to the documentation on type-conversion: https://github.com/intuit/karate#type-conversion

It is not possible to figure out based on the incomplete information you have provided. Still let me try, I think you have done some mistake in string concatenation before calling this function. And the value of `featurepath` is completely wrong.

In the example below, see how a string concatenation within a JS function leads to what you call "junk value":

```
* def fun = function(){ var temp = { hello: 'world' }; return temp + '' }
* def bar = fun()
* print "bar:", bar
```

Results in output:

```
13:52:50.912 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] bar: [object Object]
```

If you still are stuck, the only suggestion I have is follow the instructions here please: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Hi Peter, Thanks for prompt reply, from console i can see that http call ( karate.call) is correctly done and getting expected html response.. but while storing this html data from call to 'var result' is printed as 'com.intuit.karate.ScriptObjectMap@102d92c4 ' .

Comment: that does not give me any extra info at all, sorry. please submit an issue, and make sure you follow the instructions. all the best

Comment: used alternate way of using __loop and resolved this. Thanks for response